# Framermotion animate between Routes with mode="sync" not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

Example Project:
https://playcode.io/1209645

I'm trying to animate between two routes using react-router-dom and framer motion. When using mode="wait" on the AnimatePresence element the animations work as desired. When using mode="sync" the two page routes are positioned next to each other instead of being stacked.

Is this the intended behaviour or am I missing something? The effect I'm looking for is for one page to blend into the other. How can I get the two pages to cover each other?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know if you could do it with framer motion, but you can easily handle it by adding `position: absolute` and `top:0` and `left:0` to each `motion.div`

[playcode](https://playcode.io/1209756)

Comment: Does the job indeed. Adding relative to the direct parent + using "absolute inset-0" (tailwind) to fill the existing space as before, thx!